# Lazarus raising exception class after compiling program on Windows

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I've written program in Lazarus Pascal. It was entirely written on Mac, then I've switched to windows, recompiled it (recompiled .dylib to .dll, recompiled and installed custom component), and it runs, but when I try to do anything, it throws error:

While on debug mode:

`Project project1 raised exception class 'External:SIGSEGV'. At address 772CD4F1`

Running .exe file :

`Access violation.`

// EDIT

I've noticed that it has a problem with that part of code, in particular at `ListView.Clear` command:

```
procedure AddressList.updateView(ListView : TListView);
var
  element : ListElement;
  newItem : TListItem;
begin
  ListView.Clear;

  element := first;

  if element = nil then
    exit;

  while element <> nil do
  begin
    newItem := ListView.Items.Add;
    newItem.Caption := element^.name;
    newItem.SubItems.Add(element^.surname);
    newItem.SubItems.Add(element^.address);
    newItem.SubItems.Add(formatNumber(element^.phoneNumber));

    element := element^.next;
  end;

end;
```

How is that possible, what could I do wrong?

Comment: Where does `first` come from ? a dll ? It looks like a singly-listed list. Have you try to debug ? (use stack trace to find the origin of the error). Have you tried to debug your dll (for a dll: Run parameters, define host application, so that you can debug with source code in sync) ?

Comment: @BBaz First comes from AddressList class. I've noticed that when I put `ShowMessage` before `ListView.Clear` and after it, only before message shows, then the error occurs. I don't think it has something to do with the .dll

Comment: Try to debug it without the DLL first, by compiling it into an application.

Answer (score 3):

In Free Pascal Classe instances are always implicit pointers.

It seems that for some reason your `ListView` doesn't contain a properly created class instance. The "pointer" `ListView` points to wherever. When the class method `Clear`tries to access the data you get a segmentation fault.

A watch of `ListView` should show either garbage data or `<invalid>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Fortunately, i won't be needing that as I found out that I can do it only on Mac. Anyways thank you.